# Multiple radio button using php javascript ajax

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am making a survey form with multiple radio buttons.
the questions are in a database and i pick the questions and display options as radio buttons

```
<div id="question">
    <form id="pollform">;
<?php
    $i=0;
    while(list($ID,$Question,$form,$one,$two,$three,$four,$five)=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $i++; 
?>
        <p><?php echo $ID.") ".$Question; ?></p>
        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $i;?>" value="1" /> <?php echo $one; ?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $i;?>" value="2" /> <?php echo $two; ?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $i;?>" value="3" /> <?php echo $three; ?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $i;?>" value="4" /> <?php echo $four; ?><br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $i;?>" value="5" /> <?php echo $five; ?><br />
<?php 
    } 
?>
    <input type="button" id="review-submit" value="Submit" onclick="pollsubmit();">
    <form>
</div>
```

To process this and to send the selected answers using Ajax I used the following code

```
<script language=Javascript>
function pollsubmit(){
<?php
    $dbquerry="SELECT `ID`, `Question`, `Form`, `one`, `two`,`three`,`four`,`five` FROM `pollquestions` Order by `ID`";
    $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$dbquerry);
?>
    var answers = new Array();
    var form1=document.getElementById("pollform");
<?php
    $count=0;
    while(list($ID,$Question,$form,$one,$two,$three,$four,$five)=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $count++;
?>
        for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            if(form1.radio<?php echo $count;?>[i].checked) {
                answers[<?echo $ID;?>]= form1.radio<?php echo $count;?>.value;
            }
        }
<?php 
    }
?>
}
</script>
```

But this is giving me an `Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined` though in both the places the name is radio1. whereas if i use only string say for example `name="radio1"` it is working but if i use `name="radio<?php echo $i;?>"` it is not working. Can you kindly help

Comment: Are you serious about this `while(list(...) = ...)` loop? Why not assign it to an array/object and then use that one?! And why do you build a JavaScript array manually instead of using `json_encode()`?

Comment: could you check the html generate by this code.........and if you dont find error in that you can paste its here...we may look at it

Comment: check the take a poll section in [link]http://edumetric.in/disp.php?Area_ID=6&sort=Ranking&City_ID=2 the html output is there. i have used question for the name of radio button

Comment: Click take a poll for any of the schools when you press the submit button I get this error Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript for loop should start at 0. And for the value you'll need a [i].

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    if(form1.radio<?php echo $count;?>[i].checked) {
        answers[<?echo $ID;?>]= form1.radio<?php echo $count;?>.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still it is not working :( you can check the complete code in working in [link](http://edumetric.in/disp.php?Area_ID=6&sort=Ranking&City_ID=2) click take poll in the window that pops up go down and then press submit you will see the error.

Comment: You forgot to change `i<=5` to `i<5`. It's at the sixth loop its throws the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate it works. This mistake i couldnt spot and it was frustrating me for hours. Now it is solved and thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language=Javascript>
function pollsubmit(){
<?php
    $dbquerry="SELECT `ID`, `Question`, `Form`, `one`, `two`,`three`,`four`,`five` FROM `pollquestions` Order by `ID`";
    $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$dbquerry);
?>
    var answers = new Array();
    var form1=document.getElementById("pollform");
<?php
    $count=0;
    while(list($ID,$Question,$form,$one,$two,$three,$four,$five)=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $count++;
?>
        for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            if(form1.['radio<?php echo $count;?>'][i].checked) {
                answers[<?echo $ID;?>]= form1.['radio<?php echo $count;?>'].value;
            }
        }
<?php 
    }
?>
}
</script>
```

Edit:

```
for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                if(form1.['radio<?php echo $count;?>'][i].checked) {
                    answers[<?echo $ID;?>]= form1.['radio<?php echo $count;?>'].value;
                }
            }
```